# Node app and multiple node modules being developed concurrently, usage of npm-link

Tags: git, node.js, npm, require

I'm building a node.js app and also developing modules required by the app concurrently.  Some of the modules have peerDependencies and I'm struggling to figure out how to best structure my dev environment.

What I have so far:

```
/node-projects
|--/myApp
|----/node_modules
|------/symlink to module1
|------/symlink to module2
|
|--/module1
|
|--/module2
```

I use `npm link` to create a symlink in my app's node_modules to the modules in my projects root.  This lets me easily git push/pull individual modules as well as my application.

However, if module2 specifies module1 as a peerDependency my app will not start up, giving an error that module2 cannot find module1.  I assume this is because they're not actually in a node_modules directory together.

Is there a piece of the puzzle I'm missing out on that will allow module2's symlink to recognize module1's symlink?  Or is what I'm trying to accomplish just not possible with npm currently?  Is there a better strategy to keeping my custom modules in sync with git/github while also requiring them in my main app?

Comment: Same problem here! I am looking to try out `npm-workspace` soon.

Answer (score 3):

After doing some more research it seems that what I'm trying to accomplish is not currently possible using only `npm link`, and there doesn't appear to be an easy answer to getting this kind of workflow set up using only npm.

Reading through [this issue](https://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues/1400) on npm's github repo I can see that others are experiencing the same frustration, with no possible solutions given.

I also came across the module [npm-workspace](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/npm-workspace) which appears to provide a solution to my question entirely, though I have yet to try it.

Another possibility is to use [Git submodules](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules).  In reading about git submodules, however, I see a lot of complaints that they're difficult to get setup correctly, and it seems incredibly easy to accidentally include your sub modules in your main git repo.

I will wait to accept my own answer until I've had a chance to test npm-workspace, and in the mean time perhaps someone will chime in with a better solution.

Comment: npm-workspace was created specifically to solve the frustrations you described here, and now it can also be used to package your workspace for deployment (copy packages instead of linking). It's not the  perfect solution, but it will make your npm experience a lot smoother, I hope. (Disclaimer: I'm the creator of npm-workspace)

Comment: Sorry @Mario, but npm-workspace is unfortunately deficient in matters of updating downstream dependencies of a module. The copy feature of npm-workspace is nice for getting past the issues associated with npm linking, but if I want to independently develop on an upstream dependency for downstream dependencies that use npm-shrinkwrap, I have to go through a whole slew of manual steps to update all downstream dependencies. We need some sort of dependency update rollup.